# Integrating a calendar into cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob

Has anyone successfully integrated a calendar into Cartthrob? A client wants to be able to let their users select weeks in advance when a delivery can be made. Any advice?

Comment: Does cart throb provide a "ship on" field?

Answer (score 1):

From memory you would just need to add a custom date field to your order to hold the shipping date.

On the front end checkout form you would then need to include the datepicker field.

Cartthrob does some magic whereby it will add the data to your order entry. You don't really need to configure it. If there's a field that matches an input on the checkout form it will store the data for you.

Comment: This answer is correct! You can just add it as a custom field entered with the order.